# JQuery: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: jquery

So I am getting the following error when clicking the "save" element as my handler method is wrong. Could someone point me to what the error means and how it can be fixed?

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>       at HTMLUListElement. (paint:233)
>       at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLUListElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

```
(function($){        
        //get context
          var c = document.getElementById("editor").getContext("2d");                 


          tools = { 
                  save: function() { 
                    prompt("Hello");
                    }
                  crop: function() { 
                    prompt("Bye");
                    }

          }; 
          $("#toolbar").children().click(function(e) { 
              //prevent a href click
              e.preventDefault();          
              //call the relevant function 
              tools[this.id].call(this); 
          });


    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

It means tools[this.id] is undefined. 
'this' will be the actual child object which was clicked. 
You may want to check the value for "this.id"

Answer (score 1):

I needed to remove unnecessary ul and li tags from my html